# How to call a custom procedure to do additional check on a userid after successful authentication

Tags: spring-security

Our application is using the old Spring Acegi to handle authentication and there is no plan as well as funding to upgrade it to Spring security 3 anytime soon so I need to stick with it for the time being.  Basically, I would like to be able to call our custom procedure to do additional check on the userid before directing user to the target page.  I would appreciate your help very much if you could give me some suggestions on which classes I need to extend or implement on.  Your help is appreciated.

TMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application uses one SpringSecurity authentication provider (e.g.  DaoAuthenticationProvider or LdapAuthenticationProvider) the answer is simple:

1)  Override the SpringSecurity authentication provider

2)  Call in your implementation to the method authenticate of the super class.

3)  In case of success perform your additional checks. Return success or fail respectively

4)  Register your authentication provider using  tag (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/ns-config.html)

Please tell me if you need any additional help.

Best regards,
    Michael

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So in your opinion, I should write a custom UserDetailsService implementation?

Comment: If you use DaoAuthenticationProvider the simplest way is to add your additional checks to UserDetailsService. 
Please tell me if you need any additional help. 
You can accept my answer if it meet your expectation.